# Reading InputStream of NANOHTTPD gives Socket TimeOut Exception

Tags: inputstream, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream, nanohttpd

I am trying to read the InputStream from IHTTPSession.getInputStream() using the following code but its gives Socket TimeOut Exception every time.

```
private String readInStream(InputStream in){

        StringBuffer outBuffer=new StringBuffer();
        BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(in);
        try {
            while(bis.available()>0){
                int ch= bis.read();
                outBuffer.append((char)ch);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e("DATA_Length", "outputBuffer :"+outBuffer.toString().length());
        return outBuffer.toString();
    }
```

i also tried the following Method but the same exception arises

```
private String readInStream(InputStream in){
        String line="";
        StringBuffer outBuffer=new StringBuffer();

        BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        try {
            while((line=rd.readLine()) != null){
                outBuffer.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", "IOException in readInStream:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e("DATA_Length", "outputBuffer :"+outBuffer.toString().length());
        return outBuffer.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting the content length from the header and reading up to it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Can confirm the accepted answer works (getting content length from the header and reading up to it). Here is some example code to turn the `InputStream` into a `String`:

```
try {
    int contentLength = Integer.valueOf(session.getHeaders().get("content-length"));
    String msg = new String(in.readNBytes(contentLength)); // the request body
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want to prevent a `NullPointerException` here, check whether the content-length header actually exists before parsing it to an integer.